# How to create a sharing folder using Java?

Tags: java

Sorry if this question is repeated, I feel like it should be but I couldn't find any.

I'm creating a new directory let's say `C:/Docs` using the mkdirs feature `boolean carpetaCreada = directorio.mkdirs();` and this is working good, but now I want to share that folder through the network. Just as you'll do by `Right clicking -> properties -> Sharing -> Share -> Everyone -> Add -> Accept.`

Is there a way to do this through java?

I already tried

```
directorio.setReadable(true, false);
directorio.setWritable(true, false);
directorio.setExecutable(true, false);
```

But that, as I though didn't work. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Create an LDAP user entry called public that will act as a container for all public folders

```
dn: cn=public,ou=people,o=sesta.com,o=ISP
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: inetUser
objectClass: ipUser
objectClass: inetMailUser
objectClass: inetLocalMailRecipient
objectClass: nsManagedPerson
objectClass: userPresenceProfile
cn: public
mail: public@sesta.com
mailDeliveryOption: mailbox
mailHost: manatee.siroe.com
uid: public
inetUserStatus: active
mailUserStatus: active
mailQuota: -1
mailMsgQuota: 100
```

Create folders within the public account by using the mboxutil command line utility.

```
mboxutil -c user/public/gardening
```